# How to simultaneously play/stream a video and save it to app cache?

Tags: android, caching, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am developing a video playing app where an user can watch live streaming video as well as to save it app cache. I can stream a video using this code portion

```
videoView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoURL));
videoView.start();
```

I don't know how to cache the video in app storage by which user cannot modify or move the video content. So my question is How to cache a video in app storage? Is not possible or has performance issue? What are the alternative solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you ever manage to do this? @AndroidCodeHunter

Answer (score 3):

[AndroidVideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache) solves this problem. It allows stream and cache video simultaneously.

Comment: Do you have a JAR file for your library which i can use in mine?